# How do you move a picture using tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf

I've drawn a circle and I want to move it to the right and down a bit on my page.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \fill[blue!50] (10.5,0) ellipse (1.5 and 0.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

How do I do so?

Comment: Do you want to just move the ellipse inside the `tikzpicture` or do you want to move the whole `tikzpicture` environment?

Comment: move the whole environment, I'm just planning to draw an ellipse with a straight line from the origin coming up. Then just move the whole picture down and to the right.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX ! A [fully compilable MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) showcasing your use case (something to move the picture relatively to) would be useful here.

Comment: You can move the whole environment using standard LaTeX spacing commands `\hspace` and `\vspace`. I.e., put `\vspace{1in} \hspace{3em}` before the environment to move it one inch down and 3 em (plus the paragraph indentation) to the right.

Comment: Please edit your question to clarify it so people don't have to read the comments to know what you're asking. (Especially since comments are subject to deletion and therefore may not even remain here to be read.)

Answer (score 5):

As far as TeX is concerned, a `tikzpicture` is just a box with a width and height to typeset like any other box. You can use the standard LaTeX commands `\vspace` and `\hspace` to add additional vertical and horizontal space before the `tikzpicture`.

Here's a simple example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
Here's an line of text above a picture.

\begin{tikzpicture}
        \fill[blue!50] (10.5,0) ellipse (1.5 and 0.5);
\end{tikzpicture}

Yet another line of text.

\vspace{1cm}
\hspace{72pt}
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \fill[blue!50] (10.5,0) ellipse (1.5 and 0.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Two lines of text with ellipses below them.]

Note that this sort of positioning is in no way specific to `tikzpicture`.